# LayoutSubviews for Custom UITableViewCell and UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`. It has a `UIView` which is added to the "contentView" of the `UITableViewCell`. For any update, I'm redrawing that `UIView` by calling its "`setNeedsDisplay`" and implementing drawing inside "**drawRect**" method of the UIView.

The `UITableViewCell` overrides "**willTransitionToState**" and according to the bit mask value, asks the UIView to redraw.

Because I'm asking the `UIView` to redraw itself again, every time I do a "swipe to delete", I see the cell "flicker" a moment; even the text that didn't move position due to the Delete button suffers from a flicker since everything is being redrawn.

I'm aware that a possible solution is not to call "**setNeedsDisplay**" of the UIView from the "**willTransitionToState**" but instead call "**setNeedsLayout**" and have the UIView implement "**layoutSubviews**".

This is where I'm stuck at: how can I re-layout my `UIView` since everything inside my `UIView` is "**drawn**" (I use "drawInRect" and "drawAtPoint" methods for strings and images). There is also a string on the right side that I wanna hide when the "**Delete**" button appears (like in the Messages app in iPhone).

How can I do this by doing re-layout instead of re-draw?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an issue with your approach. Rather than draw everything, it's better to set up your subviews in an init method, or in the NIB.

In the `willTransitionToState` method, update whatever subviews according to the state transition.

In `layoutSubviews`, update each subview's origin and size as required.

Here's some detail from the `willTransitionToState` documentation. Although, I'm sure you'd have seen this already:

> Subclasses of UITableViewCell can implement this method to animate additional changes to a cell when it is changing state. UITableViewCell calls this method whenever a cell transitions between states, such as from a normal state (the default) to editing mode. The custom cell can set up and position any new views that appear with the new state. The cell then receives a layoutSubviews message (UIView) in which it can position these new views in their final locations for the new state. Subclasses must always call super when overriding this method.